# How to add new column (and populate it) in Entity Framework __MigrationHistory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6, my case is very simple, I need to add a new column in the `__MigrationHistory` table that should have the datetime (like a timestamp) of the created date.

I read some examples where it says how to rename `MigrationHistory` or even rename the primary key column - this is not what I want, so please don't give me that example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx)

I just need to add a `createdDate` column, and when you use `update-database -script` that new column should be equal to `dateTime.now()`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `MigrationId` column already as the datestamp of the migration creation.

```
MigrationId
201407221811141_InitTables
```

If you are trying to get the date of when the migration was **applied** you should be able to create a migration that runs a SQL script to add a column with a default value:

**pseudo code:**

```
Migration {
    Up() {
        SQL('Alter table __MigrationHistory add createdDate datetime')
        SQL('Alter table __MigrationHistory ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR createdDate')
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the date when the migration is executed on the database, not the date when the migration is created to the proyect. Your second solution, not sure that is going to work, because you are adding a new column and that will cause a schema changed exception, there are some steps to add a new column in order to achieve that. Nevertheless, a constraint or a trigger could be a solution but i´m trying to avoid that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I haven't tried this. Did you try it? Since the `__MigrationHistory` isn't part of schema/model I wouldn't think it be an issue. If you find a solution, be sure to post what you did, I'd love to know